# How to obtain all the recent files based on a prefix on a bucket S3?

Tags: python, bash, amazon-s3, airflow

I need to obtain all the files greater than a timestamp, with a prefix condition. For example, all the files that contains `myfile*.zip > 2019-11-11 13:00:00,000` so if I received the following:

```
myfile1.zip - 2019-11-10 13:00:00,000
myfile2.zip - 2019-11-11 10:00:00,000
myfile3.zip - 2019-11-11 13:00:00,000
myfile4.zip - 2019-11-11 17:00:00,000
```

I wanna have the next result:

```
myfile3.zip - 2019-11-11 13:00:00,000
myfile4.zip - 2019-11-11 17:00:00,000
```

I need to do that with Python boto3, or bash, or with Airflow S3KeySensor.

Answer (score -1):

Bash solution:

You can use a combination of `touch -t` and `find -newer`.  `touch` will create a file with a certain modified date, and `find -newer` will only list files that are newer than the created file. For example:

```sh
# for 2019-11-11 13:00:00,000
# Edit: This is currently in the future, so no results for you!
touch -t 201911111300 mytempfile.temp 
find . -name 'myfile*.zip' -newer mytempfile.temp
rm mytempfile.temp
```

From `touch --help`:

```
-t STAMP               use [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss] instead of current time
    --time=WORD        change the specified time:
                         WORD is access, atime, or use: equivalent to -a
                         WORD is modify or mtime: equivalent to -m
```

Comment: But that solution is not on top of Amazon S3, the solution that you propose is for a "normal" file system